# Vuetify how to add the styles to a label inside of a v-checkbox

Tags: vue.js, vuetify.js

I am having trouble giving the label styles inside of my vuetify v-checkbox component. Here is the documentation https://vuetifyjs.com/en/components/checkboxes/. I basically want to use CSS to change the color of the text that goes in the "label" part of the checkbox. Thank you

Answer (score 0):

You could target the checkbox's label with the `.v-input__control .v-label` selector:

```css
.v-input__control .v-label {
  color: red;
}
```

[demo](https://codepen.io/tony19/pen/PoWMroG)

Answer (score 0):

You can use the label slot of v-checkbox to style it however you want:

```
 <v-checkbox>
   <template slot="label">
     <div style="color: red">
       label
     </div>
   </template>
 </v-checkbox>
```